# Pin down a div with css or javascript?

Tags: jquery, css

I'll try to give an example before I say more clearly about my question, here is the site:
http://webdesignerwall.com

I just want to program like this, make the left content can slide vertically when I drag  the scrollbar or make the left and right content is fixed, the center content can slide up and down just look like this:

http://mondaybynoon.com

Any idea how to do it with css or jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the div which you want to make stationary fixed.

eg:

```
#Fixed{
position:fixed top left; width:100px; height:800px; background:#99FF99;}
```

Comment: +1-ish: it's also worth mentioning that the sample site has responsive design. Without taking care to accomodate narrow viewports, the fixed position menu will simply overlap the content.

Comment: ..or slip behind it, actually.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic way to do this is to set the CSS position property of a div to fixed:

```
<div style="position:fixed;"> .. div content .. </div>
```

then place the content you wish to be fixed in your div.